# storing values from fb messenger bot into dialog flow

Tags: facebook, bots, facebook-messenger, dialogflow-es

i am trying to build a simple bot using dialog flow and fb messenger. i have requirement to show two buttons to the end user to pick a cake type. i am able to show the options using the below custom response:

```
{
  "facebook": {
    "attachment": {
      "type": "template",
      "payload": {
        "template_type": "button",
        "text": "What kind of cake would you like?",
        "buttons": [
          {
            "type": "postback",
            "payload": "witheggs",
            "title": "Contain Eggs"
          },
          {
            "type": "postback",
            "payload": "noeggs",
            "title": "Eggless"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

once user tap one of the two buttons then how do i set it to some variable in dialog flow and then ask next set of question?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what language you're using but here's what you're looking for:

The *payload* part is returned by api.ai as *resolvedQuery* when the user clicks any button.

For example, if the user clicks on *Contain Eggs*, api.ai will return *witheggs* through the *resolvedQuery* node of the json.

Does that help? Feel free to ask if there's anything else.

Comment: how do i assign this value back into  a parameter in my dialogflow action?

Comment: If you tell me exactly what your requirement is, I can help you. Just give me a scenario. Because from what I understand from your question, you just want to send it back. Really? Not display it? I need to understand what you're asking about.

Comment: ok well here it is:  user on fb says: I want a cake. the bot replied which one with two buttons: Eggs, Eggless.  whichever user clicks, i want to ask next question. that's it now i m having trouble how the slected button postback will assign the value to the parameter in dialogflow?

Comment: I think you've it a little bit confused. Here's what I did when I had to do the same:  Like I meantioned inbky previous comment, after Ingot the resolvedQuery, I used my webhook to process some info. Now that I had it, I sent the info back to api.ai using the webhook itself. If I had to store the values(sessionId in my case), I used my sql db to do it. Does this help?

Comment: well not really. but yes i accept i may be confused here. take it this way: i sent a payload containing buttons to fb messenger (which of course goes via webhook). user clicked one of the two buttons i sent. Now i need to set the response to my api.ai parameters. i am expecting to put some expression in the input parameter value to get this value. as webhook returns the response from button clicked so i do not expect to write extra code. please advise

Comment: Why do you need to set the response to your api.ai as a parameter? It is already being sent back in the resolvedQuery node of the response JSON. You can simply use that.

Comment: any example on how to refer that?

Comment: I don't have my laptop with me, else I'd have given you one. Sorry for that.

Comment: can i get ur email id to talk a bit?

Comment: Just send me a msg in fb at fb.com/jacobceles